# construct a large dask-backed xarray from an iterator of row vectors

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

How can I build xarray from from an iterator of row vectors.
The resulting array may be larger than memory and will be backed by a dask array.
The row vectors also come with unique labels which need to become the row index of the resulting xarray.
In the docs I only see a constructor that takes an in memory numpy array to begin with.

An example use case would be to store a [word embedding model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) as an  xarray with words as row labels. These models usually provide an iterator that produces (string, vector) pairs over all words in the vocabulary. Most models have have in the 100s of dimensions and there are usually ~10^6 words in the vocabulary. I would like to stack the vectors into a matrix in order to perform linear algebra operations and also be able to look up rows by the word string.

I would expect to be able to write something like:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

vectors = (('V'+str(i), np.random.randn(10000)) for i in range(10**9))
xray = xarray_from_iter(vectors)
xray.to_parquet('big_xarray.parquet')
row1234567 = xray['V1234567']
```

Does xarray provide something like `xarray_from_iter`?
If not how do I write it?
`xarray_from_iter` should work something like `numpy.fromiter`
except that it should also label the rows as it goes.
It would also need to delay the computation until dump was called,
since the whole issue is that the that array is larger than memory.

Comment: if you can provide a MCVE ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that describes the workflow you're attempting, I'd be happy to put together an answer of how this might work. As it is now, its hard for me to tell where your question is coming from.

Comment: @jhamman the main use case I have in mind is to store a word embedding model as an xarray with words as row labels.

Comment: I suggest you provide an example with either a simplified version of what you are trying to do or some pseudo-code.

Comment: @jhamman I have added a minimal example of what I need.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; xarray does not have a from iterator constructor. You'll have to build your dask arrays yourself.

*Also, xarray does not have a `to_parquet` method so that is not an operation you can do (at the moment).*

Here is an example of how you might construct a dask array (and `xarray.DataArray`) for your use case:

```
import dask.array
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

num = 10

names = []
arrays = []
for i in range(num):
    names.append('V'+str(i))
    arrays.append(dask.array.random.random(10000, chunks=(1000,)))

da = xr.DataArray(data, dims=('model', 'sample'), coords={'model': names})

print(da)
```

Yielding:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'stack-ff07239b7ea24834ba59f2d05b7f41e2' (model: 10, 
sample: 10000)>
dask.array<shape=(10, 10000), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 1000)>
Coordinates:
  * model    (model) <U2 'V0' 'V1' 'V2' 'V3' 'V4' 'V5' 'V6' 'V7' 'V8' 'V9'
Dimensions without coordinates: sample
```

This is not likely to be efficient, especially when the length of the iterator gets large (like in your example). It may be worth proposing such a constructor on the dask github issues page.

Comment: @jhaman the main problem I am trying to solve is to build an xarray that is larger than memory. I am happy to build it out of chunks myself if there is no constructor, but I need to be able to build it incrementally while keeping most of it out of core.  While I prefer parquet, I can work with netcdf or hdf5. The showstopper is constructing a 10^7 by 10^3 xarray.  I can not build all the chunks in memry first.

Comment: @DanielMahler - I suspected that would be the case. I suggest you open an issue with dask to discuss a new feature streaming arrays from an iterator.